# Min.CSS files. Where does their assignment typically occur within Wordpress themes?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, min

Someone min'ed a wordpress theme's css file, and I don't see it being referenced in the header.php file. I checked the origin file in functions, too, just to see if it was min'ed there, and added in (seemed unlikely). It is a massive pain in the rear to hunt through the regs stylesheet, and then search out the min to test. (I'm modifying a template). Want to use the uncompressed stylesheet. This won't be a high traffic site, I don't think the min will make too much of a difference.

Does anyone know where this min.css file would be hiding? Is there a best practices for this? I looked around... not finding it. hah.

Is there a trick piece of php somewhere doing this?

Comment: could be minified on the fly by a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually registered by (conditionally) calling `wp_enqueue_style()`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

---

Edit: and as point out by diggy, it might be minified on the fly, e.g. by a caching plugin.

Comment: `code` wp_enqueue_style( 'origin_fancybox-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css', false, 1.0, 'screen' );  

This is what I got. It doesn't reference the style.min.css anywhere that I can find. I'm so stumped. Doesn't reference the orginal style mins. Is there anywhere else I should be looking?

Comment: I've absolutely no idea of the theme you're using, but there assuredly is a place where it's registering something ending with `.min.css`.

Comment: Denis-  you're right. Because, really there's no possible way it's not registering somewhere. But, where is the question. P.S., I'm using a theme called Origin as a base. It uses fancybox.... The only thing that was under wp_enqueue_style() were the fancybox stylesheets.

Comment: There are plenty of wp_enqueue_style calls in that theme, along with this check for a define: `$suffix = ( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) ? '' : '.min';`. Add `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);` in your `wp-config.php` file.